# How do you write test code for custom processing such as tabulator headerclick in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am using Tabulator in Angular.
I have added my own processing in headerClick, but I don't know how to write the test code for that.

```
column: any[] = [
    {title:"Name",
     field:"name",
     width:150,
     headerClick: (e:any, column:any) => {
       // here
     }
    },
  ];

private drawTable(): any {
    var tabulator = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      data: this.tableData,
      reactiveData:true,
      columns: this.column,
      layout: 'fitData',
    });
    
    document.getElementById('my-tabular-table').appendChild(this.tab);

    return tabulator
  }
```

If anyone knows, I would like to know.

Comment: can't you just define the header click function on it's own and then just test it? so the test code calls the function directly

Comment: then I'd look into integration tests if that's more what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you Matthias.
I did not know I could do that.
I will try the integration test again.